# Laravel sanctum with Vue 3 API calls

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-sanctum

I'm building an app, with Laravel backend and Vue3. Both apps are on different domains. I'm doing axios API calls from Vue. On Laravel I have Sanctum installed to handle my authorisation, login, etc... I tried a lot of stuff, from storing token to localStorage (not a good practice as it is not secured). So I read more, found out that I have to just send - `withCredentials: true` and it will handle everything with a cookie, out of the box. It does not work. Then I read that it does not work if they are on different domains. I'm not sure how to handle this anymore.

Is this all true? Is sanctum way to go?If not, what is the best way for secured auth? Will it work on same domains and is there a way to work with different domains?

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Check this answer  may be helpful for Your. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711543/is-there-a-way-to-have-sanctum-on-diffrent-domains

Answer (score 0):

having 2 domains doesn't change anything. The logic is very simple. basically you have a token (key) and you will communicate with this key. you will send the token to the client when the conditions are met. than after, client say "if this your token, give my credentials."

just use sanctum token:

```
  $user->createToken($request->name)->plainTextToken;
```

than you return Bearer token if the conditions are met:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

and protect your route with sanctum middleware:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request)
```

finally if the key is correct:

```
return response($user, 200);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this was not my issue. I now made the proxy using vue.config.js . But my issue is that Sanctum is not returning the cookie on my request, just the token that I don't need to use.