# Laravel Sanctum: (Frontend & Backend with different IP Address) Error: Login CSRF Token mismatch

Tags: laravel, axios, token, csrf, sanctum

Having CSRF token mismatch error in login with Nuxt and Laravel Sanctum.

But when I change the URL of both apps (frontend & backend) into localhost, the login works perfectly.

But if I set:

FRONTEND_URL=https://127.0.0.11

BACKEND_URL=https://127.0.0.10

CSRF token mismatch error occurs. Is there any workaround?

[image]
[image]

config/cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

Comment: could you post your `config/cors.php` file? You could try to fix it by adding `*` to `paths`. If that fixes it then it's worth changing it to your actual front end address, i.e. `https://127.0.0.11`.

Comment: I have added the config/cors.php, I'm just trying to make this work with two different address/server for deployment.

Comment: I think cross-site CSRF Token is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64711543/12104911